# Ceramic capacitors in series to increase AC voltage rating

Tags: capacitor, ac, ceramic, balancing

If I put 4 of 1uFx100V cercaps in series I will virtually have one .25uFx400V capacitor.

As I know I should use balancing resistors for even distributinon of the voltage across the capacitors. However if I skip them in the simulation I did not find any diviance in the voltage - no matter which ESR or parallel resistance deviance I put into model.

So my conclusion is that **in case of AC (no DC) there is no need for balancing resistors**. Is that correct?

Comment: Did you try your simulation with slightly varying capacitance values? Tolerance means that no 2 caps will have exactly the same value ...

Comment: Thanks, @brhans. That's really made the difference. However balancing resistors did not help in this case either :( I tried 100k resistors (less resistance made the the power dissipation too big for my application)

Comment: Parallel resistors will only help DC voltage distribution due to mismatch is leakage. Depending on application you are more likley to encounter problems due to +-20 % difference in capacitance.

Comment: In case you are, you should not use 4 ceramic caps in series to run on 240Vac line.  That requires an X1 rated plastic cap.  These will be bulky since the Dk is much lower but AC line must withstand HV spikes.